# How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS on GKE running through Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

with the help of kubernetes I am running daily jobs on GKE, On a daily basis based on cron configured in kubernetes a new container spins up and try to insert some data into BigQuery.

The setup that we have is we have 2 different projects in GCP in one project we maintain the data in BigQuery in other project we have all the GKE running so when GKE has to interact with different project resource my guess is I have to set an environment variable with name  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS which points to a service account json file, but since every day kubernetes is spinning up a new container I am not sure how and where I should set this variable.

Thanks in Advance!

## NOTE: this file is parsed as a golang template by the drone-gke plugin.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-data-service-account-credentials
type: Opaque
data:
  sa_json: "bas64JsonServiceAccount"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: adtech-ads-apidata-el-adunit-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: adtech-ads-apidata-el-adunit-container
    volumeMounts:
    - name: service-account-credentials-volume
     mountPath: "/etc/gcp"
     readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: service-account-credentials-volume
    secret:
      secretName: my-data-service-account-credentials
      items:
      - key: sa_json
        path: sa_credentials.json
```

---

## This is our cron jobs for loading the AdUnit Data

```
apiVersion: batch/v2alpha1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: adtech-ads-apidata-el-adunit
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  suspend: false
  concurrencyPolicy: Replace
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 10
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 10
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: adtech-ads-apidata-el-adunit-container
            image: {{.image}}
            args:
            - -cp
            - opt/nyt/DFPDataIngestion-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
            - com.nyt.cron.AdUnitJob
            env:
              - name: ENV_APP_NAME
                value: "{{.env_app_name}}"
              - name: ENV_APP_CONTEXT_NAME
                value: "{{.env_app_context_name}}"
              - name: ENV_GOOGLE_PROJECTID
                value: "{{.env_google_projectId}}"
              - name: ENV_GOOGLE_DATASETID
                value: "{{.env_google_datasetId}}"
              - name: ENV_REPORTING_DATASETID
                value: "{{.env_reporting_datasetId}}"
              - name: ENV_ADBRIDGE_DATASETID
                value: "{{.env_adbridge_datasetId}}"
              - name: ENV_SALESFORCE_DATASETID
                value: "{{.env_salesforce_datasetId}}"
              - name: ENV_CLOUD_PLATFORM_URL
                value: "{{.env_cloud_platform_url}}"
              - name: ENV_SMTP_HOST
                value: "{{.env_smtp_host}}"
              - name: ENV_TO_EMAIL
                value: "{{.env_to_email}}"
              - name: ENV_FROM_EMAIL
                value: "{{.env_from_email}}"
              - name: ENV_AWS_USERNAME
                value: "{{.env_aws_username}}"
              - name: ENV_CLIENT_ID
                value: "{{.env_client_id}}"
              - name: ENV_REFRESH_TOKEN
                value: "{{.env_refresh_token}}"
              - name: ENV_NETWORK_CODE
                value: "{{.env_network_code}}"
              - name: ENV_APPLICATION_NAME
                value: "{{.env_application_name}}"
              - name: ENV_SALESFORCE_USERNAME
                value: "{{.env_salesforce_username}}"
              - name: ENV_SALESFORCE_URL
                value: "{{.env_salesforce_url}}"
              - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
                value: "/etc/gcp/sa_credentials.json"
              - name: ENV_CLOUD_SQL_URL
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: secrets
                    key: cloud_sql_url
              - name: ENV_AWS_PASSWORD
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: secrets
                    key: aws_password
              - name: ENV_CLIENT_SECRET
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: secrets
                    key: dfp_client_secret
              - name: ENV_SALESFORCE_PASSWORD
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: secrets
                    key: salesforce_password


          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

---

Answer (score 59, accepted):

So, if your GKE project is project `my-gke`, and the project containing the services/things your GKE containers need access to is project `my-data`, one approach is to:

- Create a service account in the `my-data` project. Give it whatever GCP roles/permissions are needed (ex. `roles/bigquery.
  dataViewer` if you have some BigQuery tables that your `my-gke` GKE containers need to read).

  - Create a service account key for that service account. When you do this in the console following https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys, you should automatically download a `.json` file containing the SA credentials.
- Create a Kubernetes secret resource for those service account credentials. It might look something like this:

  ```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Secret
  metadata:
    name: my-data-service-account-credentials
  type: Opaque
  data:
    sa_json: <contents of running 'base64 the-downloaded-SA-credentials.json'>
  ```
- Mount the credentials in the container that needs access:

  ```
  [...]
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: my-container
      volumeMounts:
      - name: service-account-credentials-volume
        mountPath: /etc/gcp
        readOnly: true
  [...]
    volumes:
    - name: service-account-credentials-volume
      secret:
        secretName: my-data-service-account-credentials
        items:
        - key: sa_json
          path: sa_credentials.json
  ```
- Set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable in the container to point to the path of the mounted credentials:

  ```
  [...]
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: my-container
      env:
      - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
        value: /etc/gcp/sa_credentials.json
  ```

With that, any official GCP clients (ex. the GCP Python client, GCP Java Client, gcloud CLI, etc. should respect the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var and, when making API requests, automatically use the credentials of the `my-data` service account that you created and mounted the credentials `.json` file for.

Comment: Does `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` also work if it is just being made available as an env var or does it always have to point to a mounted file?

Comment: I believe the value of the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var always has to be a path to a credentials file to work correctly. As in, having the base64 encoded or some other representation of the credentials directly as the value of the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var will not work.

Comment: Replace "data" on our Secret, with "stringData" if we wanna put text of our GCP Service Account json file:

Comment: stringData:
  sa_json: |-
    {
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "<project_id>",
      "private_key_id": "<private_key_id>",
      "private_key": "<private_key>",
      "client_email": "<client_email>",
      "client_id": "<auth_uri>",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "<client_x509_cert_url>"
    }