# Error io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers

I'm approaching to Google Cloud Platform, and I've followed [Deploying a containerized web application](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app) and I've *successfully* deployed a small Spring Boot service that uses Cloud Vision API (I'm using the Java client linked at the Vision webpage).

My issue is that when I call the service, I receive the following error message: `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`. Such error appears when the client try to call the Cloud Vision API. I haven't such issue in my local installation of the service because I manually set the environment variable that points to the Google credentials file.

Any hints on what could be the cause of my issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [environment variable and the path](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) in your container configuration. You could use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023291/5880234) to have an idea on how to mount the credentials and the environment variable within the container configuration.