# Use kubernetes secret with GKEPodOperator in Airflow

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, airflow, kubernetes-secrets, docker-secrets

I am trying to use a GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS secret with GKEPodOperator.
Basically I want to:
1. Upload the secret to GKE
2. Mount (?) the secret to a container
3. Use the secret when running the container.

Until now I have added the key.json-file to my image at build time, and I know this is not the correct way to do it.

I found this question: [How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS on GKE running through Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021469/how-to-set-google-application-credentials-on-gke-running-through-kubernetes)

The difference is that they are not using GKEPodOperator.

What I have done:
1. Created the secret using:

`kubectl create secret generic mysupersecret --from-file=service_account_key=key.json`

I see there are `volumes` and `volume_mounts` parameters but I dont understand how to use them.

Can anyone give me a helping hand on this? Maybe I am about to do something stupid..

Answer (score 0):

[To use a Secret with your workloads, you can specify environment variables that reference the Secret's values, or mount a volume containing the Secret.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/secret#using_a_secret)
Please follow this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets) to using secrets and set volumes and volume_mounts.

This link [refer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform) to the Google general document for Authenticating to Cloud Platform with Service Accounts to use a GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS secret. And this [link](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator) describes how to use the KubernetesPodOperator to launch Kubernetes pods.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to passing secrets to the `KubernetesPodOperator`.
[Check details here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator).

Here is quick sample.

```
influx_username = secret.Secret(
...
)
influx_pass = secret.Secret(
...
)
operator = GKEPodOperator(
    task_id='task-id',
    project_id='prj-id',
    location='location',
    cluster_name='cluster-name',
    name='pod-name',
    namespace='default',
    image='image-path',
    secrets=[influx_username, influx_pass],
)
```