# Passing GCP service account key to GKE pods

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-iam

I have created in TF (`0.11.14`) a GCP role, attached it to a service account and also created a key for the later as follows:

```
resource "google_service_account_key" "my_service_account_key" {
  service_account_id = "${google_service_account.my_service_account.id}"
}
```

I then take the `private_key` as output in the following way:

```
output "my_service_account_private_key" {
  value       = "${google_service_account_key.my_service_account_key.private_key}"
  sensitive   = true
}
```

Which prints me a very long string in the likes of

```
ewogICJK49fo34KFo4 .... 49k92kljg==
```

Assuming the role has permissions enabling read/write to a GCS bucket, how can I pass the above credential / private key to a (GKE) pod / deployment, so that the pods are granted the specific service account (and therefore are able to perform what the corresponding permissions allow, as for example reading / writing to a bucket)?

Comment: My advice: Forget the service account key file and use [workload identity feature](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main steps are

1. Create a service account.
2. Provide necessary roles for your service account to work with GCS bucket.
3. Save the account key as a Kubernetes Secret.
4. Use the service account to configure and deploy an application.

I believe you got steps 1 and 2 covered. I researched for two examples ([1](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021469/how-to-set-google-application-credentials-on-gke-running-through-kubernetes.)) that might be of some assistance for the remaining steps .